# multiple definition and first defined here error for C code

Tags: c

I am getting the below error when i try to compile my code. The code is not complete since i am yet to add functions in my header and source files. But only with definitions i am having these errors.

Error:

```
 'Building target: UART_example.elf'
 'Invoking: ARM gcc linker'
 arm-xilinx-eabi-gcc -Wl,-T -Wl,../src/lscript.ld -L../../test_bsp/ps7_cortexa9_0/lib -o "UART_example.elf"  ./src/helloworld.o    ./src/platform.o ./src/uart_new.o   -Wl,--start-group,-lxil,-lgcc,-lc,--end-group
 ./src/uart_new.o:(.data+0x0): multiple definition of `uart_fifo_rxptr'
 ./src/helloworld.o:(.data+0x0): first defined here
 ./src/uart_new.o:(.data+0x4): multiple definition of `uart_rxbuf'
 ./src/helloworld.o:(.data+0x4): first defined here
 ./src/uart_new.o:(.data+0x8): multiple definition of `uart1_tx'
 ./src/helloworld.o:(.data+0x8): first defined here
 ./src/uart_new.o:(.data+0xc): multiple definition of `uart2_tx'
 ./src/helloworld.o:(.data+0xc): first defined here
 collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
 make: *** [UART_example.elf] Error 1
```

My uart_new.c source file just contains the include of uart_new.h header.

Content of uart_new.h is shown below

```
#ifndef UART_NEW_H_
#define UART_NEW_H_

#include "xparameters.h"

// address offset for the UART Peripheral
#define BASE_UART_BUFFER 0x4800
#define BASE_UART_REGS   0x4C00

unsigned *uart_fifo_rxptr =  XPAR_SIGNAL_CONNECTOR_0_S00_AXI_BASEADDR +   BASE_UART_REGS*4; // register 0

unsigned *uart_rxbuf = XPAR_SIGNAL_CONNECTOR_0_S00_AXI_BASEADDR + BASE_UART_BUFFER*4 ; // dual-port RAM

//--UART1 and UART2 transmit byte at registers 1 and 2
unsigned *uart1_tx =  XPAR_SIGNAL_CONNECTOR_0_S00_AXI_BASEADDR + (BASE_UART_REGS +1)*4; // register 1
unsigned *uart2_tx =  XPAR_SIGNAL_CONNECTOR_0_S00_AXI_BASEADDR + (BASE_UART_REGS +2)*4; // register 2

#endif /* UART_NEW_H_ */
```

And my main contains as shown below

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "platform.h"

#include "uart_new.h"


void print(char *str);

int main()
{
  //code
}
```

Please let me know if i am making any mistake somewhere.
I am assuming the error is linker related but cannot solve.
Thanks for help in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've defined some global variables in a *header file*. These global variables will subsequently be defined in *each* source file (compilation unit) that includes the header file, resulting in multiple definitions.

To fix, change your definitions to declarations in the header file:

```
unsigned *uart_fifo_rxptr, *uart_rxbuf, *uart1_tx, *uart2_tx;
```

and put the definitions in only *one* source file.